# can I used the Crypto++ to decrypt the aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 (the file is encrypted by linux dm-crypt)

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, crypto++

Did anyone have to use the Crypto++ to decrypt the file with aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 which is encrypted by linux dm-crypt?
I tried to used the following code to decrypt the file.
But it is incorrect.
Does anyone have the experience before?
Can you help me?
Thanks so much.

```
void decrypt_file(const char* password,
                  const char* inputFileName, const char* outputFileName)
{
    byte pass[ AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
    byte iv[16];
    byte head_file[16]; 
    memset(iv, 0, 16);

    try
    {
      StringSource(password, true,
        new HashFilter(*(new CryptoPP::SHA256),
          new ArraySink(pass,AES::BLOCKSIZE)));

      CryptoPP::AES::Decryption
        aesDecryption(pass, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);

      CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption
        cbcDecryption( aesDecryption, iv );

      StreamTransformationFilter *decryptor =
        new StreamTransformationFilter(cbcDecryption,
          new FileSink(outputFileName),
          StreamTransformationFilter::BlockPaddingScheme::ZEROS_PADDING);

      FileSource(inputFileName, true, decryptor);
    }
    catch(CryptoPP::Exception &e)
    {
      printf("Exception \n");
      cout << "std::exception caught:" << endl << e.what();
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Incorrect in what way? Does it fail to compile? Does it throw an exception? You need to provide more details.

Comment: Please answer irobot's question, dear new user, or I'll vote to close.

Comment: As I understand it, ESSIV uses something related to the physical sector of the file as the IV. Where is the IV coming from and being set?